# Why array index not increment? it's just replacing the value

Tags: php, html

I am trying to insert value into array by taking input from HTML input element "text". I am able to insert value into array but after inserting value in array it is replacing value at index 0 and not increment the index to 1 and so on.

I have tried using array_push() function and simple $list[] = "a";. but both ways it results the same output.

```
<html>
<body>
    <form name="f1" action="#" method="POST">
    Enter Any No.: <input type="text" name="inpbox">
    <br>
    <input type="submit" name="add" value="Add">
    </form>
    <br>
</body>
</html>
<?php
    $val = $_POST["inpbox"];
    $list=[];
    array_push($list,$val);
    print_r($list);
?>
```

Actual output:
Array ( [0] => 5)

inserting 6, 
it will result like this Array ( [0] => 6) not as expected output.

Expecting output:
Array ( [0] => 5, [1] => 6)

Note: We can insert any type of value like number(55,8,6) or strings('aa','f')

Comment: The value of PHP variables is not normally held across separate page requests.  You will need to use something like SESSIONs to retain data that way.

Comment: Thanks @ Nigel Ren.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To store state on the server, you need to use something like [PHP Sessions](http://php.net/manual/en/intro.session.php). They allow storage of values which can then be retrieved on a subsequent page access. For your example, something like this would work:

```
<?php
    session_start();
?>
<html>
<body>
    <form name="f1" method="POST">
    Enter Any No.: <input type="text" name="inpbox">
    <br>
    <input type="submit" name="add" value="Add">
    </form>
    <br>
</body>
<?php
    if (isset($_POST["inpbox"])) {
        $val = $_POST["inpbox"];
        // any values stored yet?
        if (!isset($_SESSION['list'])) {
            // no, create the list
            $_SESSION['list'] = array($val);
        }
        else {
            // yes, add this value to the list
            $_SESSION['list'][] = $val;
        }
        print_r($_SESSION['list']);
    }
?>
</html>
```

**Note**

The call to [`session_start`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php) **must** occur before any output is made as the default mode of operation of sessions is to use cookies and the headers to set cookies must be sent before any other output.

Comment: Thanks @Nick, now its working as i expected. Thanks a lot.